# Make iphone camera as a magnifying lens

Tags: iphone, camera

I have an application called magnifying lens .Here I need to start the camera at the time of appliaction starts itself.How can I possible to start the camera while starting the app?

I have the camera active code here

```
    // Create image picker controller
  UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

  // Set source to the camera
    imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

  // Delegate is self
    imagePicker.delegate = self;

  // Allow editing of image ?
    imagePicker.allowsImageEditing = NO;

  // Show image picker
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

But I don't know where to place this code for start the camera at the time when the application starts.I put the code in the viewdidLoad method .But it didn't give me the desired result.

I am very new to this if you can suggest me an idea it will be very useful to me.

Thanks in advance
Priya

Answer (score 1):

@ Priya,

Where did you put that code? in app delegate the code won't work. first add a viewController's view to window. then in that view controller's viewDidLoad method put your code. Let me know your feedback

Comment: I have created a utility application.So it has a mainviewcontroller and flipviewcontroller.I put this code in the mainviewcontrollers viewdidload method

Comment: I put the code in viewdidload of mainviewcontroller also .but has no effect.

Comment: @rahul.Thank you .I changed the source type.its my mistake I corrected

Comment: Can you please help me how to customise the camera >now my application load the camera.I need to make it customise and add new roller image in place of camera image.How I make it possible?

Comment: @Priya search for iPhone Camera overlay controls also refer to the urls below
http://iphonelovers.co.cc/search/camera-overlay-toolbar/

http://www.iuniqable.com/screenshots/

Answer (score 0):

@Priya Ok I solved the issue. Put your code in viewDidAppear method. Implement the method on mainviewController. Here is what I did added Protocols in the interface file like this 
`@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate >` and here is the viewDidAppear method

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

        // Set source to the camera
    imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        // Delegate is self
    imagePicker.delegate = self;

        // Allow editing of image ? //Deprecated
    imagePicker.allowsImageEditing = NO;

        //Use this instead
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
        // Show image picker
    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: its working.But its gone to the camera roll .I want to open the camera at the time when the apps starts .For that what I should do?